# auto redirect for a webpage is not working as it should on mobile

Tags: php, css, wordpress

its kinda of strange problem but i will try to explain it the best i can and i will attach photo links to explain more
in our woocommerce website the steps of pay the cart goes like

- press place order pic: https://prnt.sc/10hm7y5
- page for order summary pic: https://prnt.sc/10hm8d0
- page auto redirect to payment gateway site in 5sec.

now if u r doing the same in the mobile steps are:

- press place order button pic: https://prnt.sc/10hm8xp
- page for order summary .. and nothing happens .. just stay here pic: https://prnt.sc/10hmav0
- i need to press this text ” which dosnt look like a button” or something that users will notice that they need to press this now.

i dont know of the problem releated to CSS or to the payment plugin it self
what we need is .. either to fix this auto redirect or make the text” place order by tap” to look like a button so ppl will click it.

website: [www.gootalafia.com](http://www.gootalafia.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: You can design it using CSS]

For the redirection in mobile, you have to check the payment plugin setting but if you want to make it look like a button then you add some CSS.

Like this :

```
#submit_tap_payment_form{
color: white;
background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: where should i add that? in custom CSS?

Comment: Yes, you have to add this in custom CSS